# Passing data from partial view inside a modal to the main view and then close the modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a button which is defined as below in my **Index.cshtml** file:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Add Value                    
</button>
```

Clicking on button opens a modal window. My modal is defined in **Index.cshtml** file as below:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add a Value</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                        .Name("tabstrip")
                        .Items(ts =>
                        {

                            ts.Add().Text("Pick a school").Selected(true).LoadContentFrom(Url.Action("SchoolPartial", "Institution"));                            
                        })
                     )
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Below is how my partial looks like (**SchoolPartial.cshtml**):

```
<div class="col-md-12">

                @(Html.Kendo().Editor()
      .Name("schoolEditor")
      .Tag("div")
      .Tools(tools => tools
            .Clear()
            .Bold().Italic().Underline().Strikethrough()
            .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull()
            .CreateLink().Unlink()
            .InsertImage()
            .TableEditing()
            .FontColor().BackColor()
      )
      .Value(@<text><p>
                <div class="container-fluid">    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">Senior School</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p></text>))
</div>
```

Now, a user clicks on **'Add Value'** button in Index.cshtml file, **'myModal'** window opens, And in **'myModal'** window from 'Pick a school' tab, which loads the **'SchoolPartial'** tab, I want user to be able to click on the 'Senior School' div. When user clicks on senior school div in **SchoolPartial.cshtml**, I want **id = 2** to be passed to my **Index.cshtml**, which will then load the school name and address details from database and display it in **Index.cshtml**.

How can I achieve this behavior.

Thanks!

EDIT:

In my SchoolPartial.cshtml, to make my div clickable, I surrounded my div with anchor tag like below:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RetrieveSchoolDetails", "School", new {schoolId= "2" })">
       <div class="col-md-4">senior school</div>
</a>
```

Here School is my controller (**SchoolController.cs**)  and RetrieveSchoolDetails is the action method.

This is how I am defining RetrieveSchoolDetails method:

```
 public void RetrieveSchoolDetails (string schoolId= null)
        {
            var schoolDetail = db.School.Where(e => e.SchoolId== schoolId).ToList();
            string Address = Convert.ToString(schoolDetail .Select(e => e.Address));
           string Name = Convert.ToString(schoolDetail .Select(e => e.Name));
            string School= Name + Address;

            ViewBag.SchoolSelection = School;
        }
```

Now I want, once information gets into ViewBag, I want to close the modal window, so that the selection and the ViewBag information shows up in Index.cshtml.
I am not sure, how to close my bootstrap modal from controller, so that it shows me the data in Index.cshtml.
Or may be just show me the modal and user can manually close the modal, so that ViewBag information is still there. When I run my project, after assigning value to ViewBag, the browser keeps on processing and I cannot click on my modal to close it.

Please suggest!

Thanks

**EDIT 2:**

I edited my code and used, div click to call javascript function, which is then using ajax to make call to controller's method - RetrieveSchoolDetails and returning partial view from that controller method.

All it is doing now is, returns a partial view with school address in full screen. i.e it is redirecting me to my partial view with the generated school address.

However I want to close the modal and then show that partial view inside of my parent page (Index.cshtml).

Below are my code additions-

Below div is in SchoolPartial.cshtml

```
 <div onclick="GetAddress('2')" class="col-md-4">senior school</div>
```

JavaScript function

```
<script>
        function GetAddress(code)
        {                
                $.ajax({
                url: '/School/RetrieveSchoolDetails?schoolID=2',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'

            })
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#npAddress').html(result);       //npAddress is id of my div inside   
                                            //Index.cshtml where I want to display the partial. 
                                           //Here I want to close the modal window 
                                           //and show Index.cshtml in it's filled state.
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            })
        };

</script>
```

Below is my controller method:

```
public void RetrieveSchoolDetails (string schoolId= null)
            {
                var schoolDetail = db.School.Where(e => e.SchoolId== schoolId).ToList();
                string Address = Convert.ToString(schoolDetail .Select(e => e.Address));
               string Name = Convert.ToString(schoolDetail .Select(e => e.Name));
                string School= Name + Address;

                ViewBag.SchoolSelection = School;
                return PartialView("_schoolAddress");
            }
```

Below is my _schoolAddress.chtml Partial

```
@ViewBag.SchoolSelection
```

Comment: You need to use javascript/jquery to handle the `.click()` event of the `<div>` and then use ajax to pass the value to a controller method that returns a partial view of the address details and then update the DOM with that partial in the success callback (along with closing the modal). Using a link to redirect as shown in your edit is not appropriate, nor is using `ViewBag`

Comment: Thank you @Stephen! Can you please provide a sample code for this? Thanks!

Comment: What Stephen described above is correct.  You'll put an ajax call in your partial which will call the RetrieveSchoolDetails function in your controller.  You'll need to change that controller to match how we did it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849896/showing-values-from-controller-in-view-in-asp-net-mvc/36850747

Comment: @nurdyguy - Thanks for your response. I have edited my code to follow the same pattern. But it's showing partial in full screen. However want to display partial in my Index.cshtml and close the modal window.

Comment: @nurdyguy : May be my question is around, how to fill a div inside of main view from a partial view and then close the modal defined in main view.

Comment: You'll use jQuery to do that.  I'm in the middle of some stuff at work but later today I'll see if I can come up with a code sample for you.

Comment: sure.. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: To hide the modal, use $('#myModal').modal('hide') But, because you are using kendo I can't see what the actual html is going to look like so I don't know what the rest of the jQuery will look like.  (Plus, I'm not really familiar with kendo...)  Here is what I would advise though:  Don't use the partial for this.  Just write the html you want in the modal on index.cshtml.  Partials are a great tool but for this it isn't necessary and sort of over complicates things.

Comment: Only thing is.. how can I hide my modal from partial view's div click. Because my modal resides in Index.cshtml and how can I reference #mymodal in my partial view. Modal has a tab which then loads that partial view, and that is where I want the div click.

Comment: Open up the page in chrome, hit F12, and in the console type $('#myModal') and hit enter.  What does it say?

Comment: It gives me my modal definition.

Comment: That's the test to make sure it is still in the DOM.  So you can call .modal('hide') and it should close the modal.  Sure it is in a different file in the source code, but as far as the browser knows it is on the page and that is enough.

Comment: I added $('#myModal').modal('hide'); in my javascript function inside of the partial. But It's not closing the modal and neither it's assigning the value to my parent empty div. As soon as I click my div, my modal is still open, and the background page i.e. the main page, gets to the top

Comment: To close my modal, I added data-dismiss attribute to my div and it is then closing my modal. But my Javascript function is not hitting on onclick event. Please advise.

Comment: Is the entire _schoolAddress.cshtml file really just @ViewBag.SchoolSelection ?

Comment: Yes.. It just had that ViewBag Information

Comment: I got javascript function hit fixed. For some reason, it was not hitting if I add onclick attribute. But works with ("#element").click(functiom(){..})

Comment: Regarding that partial that just has ViewBag info, Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't really need to use partials here.  The purpose of using partials is to put some html code in there which needs to be reused in multiple places (different pages).  By putting it in one partial and then calling that partial from several pages you make your project easier to upkeep (any changes only need to be made once).  But, partials add a degree of complexity that is not recommended for beginners.  They can be powerful tools but lets start off with the basics and work up to that.

Second, I wouldn't use any other plugins on top of the razor (e.g. kendo).  There is nothing wrong with using it but lets keep it simple for now.  Plus, razor is pretty darn powerful on it's own.

I coded up some stuff for you but you'll have to fill in the gaps.

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyModel

<div class="">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" onclick="AddValue()">
      Add Value                    
</button> 



</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add a Value</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- some tabs here? -->
                <!-- put code for tabs here, don't use a partial -->
                <div onclick="GetAddress(2)" class="col-md-4">senior school</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<script>

    function AddValue()
    {
        $('myModal').modal();

    }

    function GetAddress(id)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/School/RetrieveSchoolDetails?schoolID' + id,
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',            
            success: function (result) {                
                $('#npAddress').text(result);                                                   
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            }
        });

    }


</script>
```

In your controller:

```
        public JsonResult RetrieveSchoolDetails (string schoolId)
        {
            // don't use a default null here unless you plan on handling it somehow
            // otherwise the next line would throw an error
            var schoolDetail = db.School.Where(e => e.SchoolId== schoolId).ToList();
            string Address = Convert.ToString(schoolDetail .Select(e => e.Address));
            string Name = Convert.ToString(schoolDetail .Select(e => e.Name));
            string School= Name + Address;
            // may need to format this depending on exactly what you want to return
            return Json(school);
        }
```

Remember, the overall learning process means starting simple and then building up to the more complex.

Comment: Thanks much @nurdyguy! You were of great help ! :)