# Data Annotate multiple CheckboxFor columns as required in MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, checkboxfor

I am having two Kendo checkboxes and I want to validate it as checking atleast one of them is required.

```
 <h4>Choose your favorite dance form</h4>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            @(Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(e => e.Salsa)
    .Name("Salsa")
    .Label("Salsa"))
            <br />
            @(Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(e => e.Latin)
    .Name("Latin")
    .Label("Latin"))
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is how my properties are defined in my Model:

```
        public bool Salsa { get; set; }

        public bool Latin { get; set; }
```

How can I data annotate them, so that atleast one is required validation takes place.

Thanks!

Comment: @nurdyguy - can u help on this